# Password protect a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a PHP page that I've defined as a view in the controller and was wondering how I'd go about password protecting this page? I couldn't get it to work using .htaccess (I could password protect the whole CodeIgniter installation folder but not individual folders or views).

The PHP page I want to password protect is inside an `admin` folder which is inside the `views` folder.

Answer (score 1):

first, on the view folder make a .htaccess file and a .htpasswd file

on .htaccess put this

```
<files page.php>
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "Restrict Access"
AuthUserFile /home/db_name/dir/dir/.htpasswd
Require user your_name
</files>
```

where it has /dir/ change for your dir's names
where it has your_name change for your login name

now go to this site

http://www.web2generators.com/apache/htpasswd_generator

to generate a .htpasswd
there you will put your user like
user: user
pass: user

it will be something like this

```
user:$apr1$sip1ow0t$taXqU/KmZL7bH/rXqqZvS0
```

put that on your .htpasswd file

now the page view.php is protect
if you want to protect the view folder put

```
<Directory /dir/dir/view>
code
</Directory>
```

Comment: I have `<files admin/adminhome.php>` in the .htaccess since the page I want to password protect is `views/admin/adminhome.php` but it's not working.

Comment: if the .htaccess is in the same directory as the page you want to protect doesnt need to specify the directory, make sure this path
AuthUserFile /home/db_name/dir/dir/.htpasswd is right, where it says db_name must be your group name, or the owner of the group
group names, are in most cases, the database name

something like /home/u932784723/views/admin/.htpasswd